# Variable set in batch file not being read

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a text file with the following values

```
datasource=c:\temp\datasource
```

Which I am then attempting to read from a batch file and populating a for loop.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%b in (config.txt) do ( 
if %%b==datasource set datasource=%%c 
) 

for %%a in (%datasource%\*.*) do if "%%~xa" == "" "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7za.exe" a -tzip -mx9 "%%a.zip" "%%a"
```

The error I get is

```
System error:
Incorrect function.

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Now if I replace `%datasource%\*.*` with `c:\temp\datasource\*.*` it works just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT0**

The results of removing `@echo off`

```
REM @echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %b in (config.txt) do (
if %b == datasource set datasource =%c
)

D:\sftp\winscp438>(
if datasource == datasource set datasource=c:\temp\datasource

)

for %a in (c:\temp\datasource\*.*) do if "%~xa
" == "" "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7za.exe" a -tzip -mx9 "%a.zip" "%a"

if "" == "" "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7za.exe" a -tzip -mx9 "c:\temp\datasource\sample.zip" "c:\temp\datasource"

7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18

Error: c:\temp\datasource\sample.zip is not supported archive


System error:
Incorrect function.
```

Comment: Do you mean you have `set datasource=c:\temp\datasource`?

Comment: @martineau - No. The datasource is simply a line in the text file

Comment: Do you have `@echo off` in your batch file?  Take it out (comment it out) and see (and tell us) what it tells you.

Comment: Sorry, thought it was part of the batch file.

Comment: @Scott - Yes I do. Have posted the results above in my post.

Comment: I just tried it locally without error. Make sure there isn't a leftover `c:\temp\datasource\sample.zip` file fouling things up.

Comment: @martineau - What do you mean by "leftover"?

Comment: Leftover from an earlier attempt -- because the error message says it's not a supported type which make me think something's wrong with it.

Comment: Sorry, gotta go -- good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are seeing is returned by 7Zip when the archive specified is invalid. This can mean either you are specifying the wrong archive type, the target file is a corrupt archive, or it is not an archive (effectively the same as being a corrupt archive).

I suspect what happened was that while you were crafting your batch file, you had initially left out the `-tzip` switch and so created `.7z` files with `.zip` extensions. Thus, when you subsequently added the switch, 7Zip looks at them and sees 7Zip files, but you are specifying zip, and so it throws the error.

Try setting things back to the way they were above, then delete `c:\temp\datasource\*.zip` and run the batch file again.

Also, assuming your directory names are stand-ins, then you should wrap your variables in quotes to avoid problems with spaces:

```
for %%a in ("%datasource%\*.*") do if …
```

Comment: I believe you mean "delete `c:\temp\datasource\*.zip`".

Comment: Yes; actually I meant to change that last night but forgot. Thanks.

Comment: Good catch on the quotes.  It made me think of the semi-obvious corollary: the datasource name must not contain any "`=`" characters, as `datasource=c:\temp\my=data` won't be parsed correctly.

Comment: Right because the equal sign is indeed a valid character for file and folder names. So many little details and catches to look out for. And people wonder why there are so many bugs in software…

Answer (score 0):

try using the set command

[Set command description](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntset.php)

Comment: I already have in the batch file. Why would I need to set it in the text file that holds the configuration values?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get it to work was to move the path `c:\temp\datasource\*.*` to the config.txt file so that the only parameter within the parenthesis was `%datasource%`. Not sure whether this is normal.